# How do I add reference to PostgreSQLCopyHelper to a .Net Core Web project?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a total newbie to the world of .Net Core and am coming up to speed on it.

I have a .Net Core web service project which talks to a PostgreSql DB (through NpgSQL).

I have a couple of other applications that utilize PostgreSQLCopyHelper to help improve performance on bulk inserts.

How do I go about adding a reference to the PostgreSQLCopyHelper to my .Net Core project? Based on notes in Git, PostgresSQLCopyHelper does work in .Net Core.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to tell Visual Studio to fetch the package from nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/PostgreSQLCopyHelper/. I think you are correct that it is .net core compatible (the nuget page indicates .NET Standard 1.3).

There are several ways to fetch it.

- Right click on the project in the solution explored, followed by 'Manage Nuget dependencies', search for 'PostgreSQLCopyHelper' in the browse tab and install.
- Install from the 'Package Manager Console' in VS by running command `Install-Package PostgreSQLCopyHelper`
- As mentioned earlier, edit the project file directly and 'restore packages' or 'build'

Hope that does it,
Neil

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the project file and include the reference.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
  <PackageReference Include="PostgreSQLCopyHelper" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Which will download the PostgreSQLCopyHelper library as well as the related dependencies as well.
[image: PostgreSQLCopyHelper - Restore packages]